# Rails - find all from parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller

I'm new to ruby and rails, I have a rails app using the socialization gem.  The gem comes with a method "followees" that returns an array of users that the current user is "following".  I'm trying to write a query that will return all of the recently created posts in order of creation from the users.

I tried this,

```
@subscribed = current_user.followees(User).all.posts.order('created_at DESC')
```

but i get the error

```
undefined method `all' for #<Array:0x0000000d5ce0b0>
```

any help is appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like you said, `#followees` returns an `Array`, which does not have an `#all` method.

Instead, you'll need to query the `Post` model directly as follows:

```
followers = current_user.followees(User)
followers_posts = Post.where(user: followers).all
```